# this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream always returning null

Tags: java, classloader

While reading a file in a web application with

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(../abc.txt)
```

is always returning null. Can anyone please provide details where should I put abc.txt in order to read. And any article on getResourceAsStream will be helpful. I have searched a lot but did not get any relevant information.

Please provide your valuable suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3803527/798818

Comment: or read the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: The answer to this is dependent on which package your class has

Comment: Thanx Mob I understand the concepts of getResourceAsStream through the elink provided by you..

Answer (score 2):

If your `abc.txt` is in `classpath` and in different package like `com/test/oops/testpaper/abc.txt`.

Then read it like below.

```
InputStream io=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/test/oops/testpaper/abc.txt");
```

For detail please go through [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: adding getClassLoader() in solved my issue.
I was using { this.getClass().getResourceAsStream() }