# Start my application from my home folder (relative path)

Tags: java, path, relative-path

This is a 100% win console application.
So here's the problem.

I want to load the file music.xm that I want to place inside the jar.
The problem come up when I try to call the file through a relative path. The start directory it's not the Java project one, but my Windows User Folder.

If I call

```
File music = new File("\\music.xm");


javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: /C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/./music/music.xm
```

If I call

```
    File music = new File(".\\music.xm");
```

I get

```
    javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: /C:/music.xm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its in your jar, you can use

```
getclassLoader().getResourceAsStream("music.xm")
```

You can use this inputStream however you like. But remember, the path should be relative to classpath root of the classloader.

In addition, if you are sure "music.xm" exists as an `independent file on filesystem` in a fixed relative location to your .class files you can also use :

```
getclassLoader().getResource("music.xm")
```

You can look [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646147/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresourceasstream-always-returning-null) and here for [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: i basically copied the music.xm in all the folder of my netbeans project but i still get a nullpointerexception.
     String path = FirstBoot.class.getClassLoader().getResource("music.xm").toString();
        System.out.print(path);
        File music = new File(path);

Comment: NPE (most probably) is because of missing resource. The resource will be looked for in your `target` directory where all your compiled code goes. Btw, how are you packaging your jar?

Comment: clean&build in netbeans, nothing particular. And inside the jar the file actually exist.

Comment: Using "music/music.xm" and creating a folder with this name inside the project i get this error:

    [ModuleFactory] Failed with loading file:/C:/Users\XXXX/Desktop/jar:file:/C:/Users/XXX/Documents/NetBeansProjects/happyh/dist/happyh.jar!/music/music.xm

quite a strange path...

Comment: That is because you are trying to access it as a file - `getResource()`. Use `getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: after few workaround i made it!
this is the snippet of code to retrieve the url (instead of the file) that i needed.  URL resourceUrl = FirstBoot.class.getClassLoader().getResource("music/music.xm");