# How do I include a text file in a javadoc comment?

Tags: java, android, javadoc

I am trying to grab a .java file that has an example on how to use my code. I have the sample in a folder called `doc-files`, as shown here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#unprocessed

What html tag do I use to include the .java file in my javadoc? I have looked all over but i cannot seem to find the tag to include text from another file in javadoc.

Edit: It is not a duplicate because I am not trying to link to another class, I am trying to embed the text of another file into the javadoc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javadoc link to src/main/resource or src/test/resource file using relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772805/javadoc-link-to-src-main-resource-or-src-test-resource-file-using-relative-path)

Comment: Not how Javadoc works.