# How to read the property file from a class file packed as a same jar

Tags: java

I want to read a property file from a java class file which the both are packed together as a same jar.

**Project Structure:**

```
src  
--->com  
------->xyz  
----------->Property(foldername)  
-------------------------------------->abc.properties  
----------->JavaClassFileFolder  
-------------------------------------->a.java
```

In the above structure folder, i want to read a `abc.properties` file from `a.java` file. I tried below methods in `a.java` file to read.

**Method1:**

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/xyz/Property/abc.properties");  
Properties prop =  new Properties();  
prop.load(in);
```

**Result**: Throws NPE at prop.load(in)

**Method 2:**

```
ClassLoader cl = Constants.class.getClassLoader();
Properties prop =  new Properties();   
prop .load(cl.getResourceAsStream("com/xyz/Property/abc.properties"));
```

**Result**: Throws NPE at prop.load(in)

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, you will need to place the resource in a directory at the package root...You'll need to find an Eclipse reference to get the full details.  If you have the Jar file, try unzipping it and checking that the `abc.properties` exists where you expect to it

Answer (score 1):

It should work. The only reason it wouldn't is that com/xyz/Property/abc.properties is not in the jar

Answer (score 1):

Start the path with a `/`, see [this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("...") and NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception/3803527#3803527).

That said:

- If you use Maven, put your property files to `src/main/resources/com/xyz/property`. Maven will do the necessary copying for you.
- Always begin your Java package names with a lower case letter, i.e. use `property` instead of `Property`. Normally, you expect only Java classes to begin with a capital letter.
- Usually, it is not necessary to work with the classloader, use `Constants.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/xyz/property/abc.properties")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

your method one has to work as far as `this` refers to class a and properties file is present at the destination you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path (no **/** at the beginning), therefore **getResourceAsStream** starts from the package of your Object (**this**). Add the **/** at the beginning and you are searching classpath absolute and because you are in the same Classloader (your Class and your Property - File are in the same jar) here are no issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an exception thrown while trying to read the InputStream object value. Try using a throws IOException class.