# How to load a resource in both IDE and .jar using the same String

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, classloader

I am confused about how java load's it's files.

```
public static File loadFile(String file) throws IOException {
    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(file);
    if(url == null){
        throw new IOException("Cannot find: " + file);
    }
    File ret;
    try {
        ret = new File(url.toURI());
        return ret;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        System.err.println("URISyntaxException in Utility.loadFile(): Tried to load: "+ file);
        throw new IOException("Cannot load: " + file);
    }
}
```

Here is an (edited) image of the project stucture in Eclipse, where loading the resource works just fine ...

[image: project structure in eclipse]

When loading the resouce, I call the above method like this:

```
char sep = File.seperatorChar;
File file = Utility.loadFile(sep + "res" + sep + "shader"
                                 + sep + "some_shader.glsl");
```

Though - here is what the .jar looks like (also edited)

[image: contents of the .jar]

As soon as I run the jar with java -jar prog.jar , I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot find: \res\shader\some_shader.glsl
```

I do not want to use any "relative" path to any kind of class, I always want to use the "absolute" path to the resource from the root of my project's structure (from .../src/... or from ... .jar!/...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load a resource in Java you alway can use '/' as separator.

Try

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("res/shader/some_shader.glsl"); // no leading slash
```

Make shure your JAR with the resource is in your JVM Classpath (`-cp` or `-classpath`).

**Edit:**
You must use `url.openStream()` to get an InputStream - **not** new File(). Your resource is not a file, becaus it is inside the JAR

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more of your enviroment. Is your whole java program in a single jar file? If you open the jar file, can you find `some_shader.glsl` under `res/shader`?

Comment: It actually WAS the usage of the systems specific file seperator AND the usage of a preceeding / in getting the URL

Comment: Nice that it works. Are you shure that you use a leading slash (/). I have tried it before a minute on Windows and Ubuntu. I have used the same jar file on both systems - no leading slash and the slash as separator (also on Windows)

Comment: Yes, the PROBLEM was the leading (/) and using (\) in my case of using File.seperatorChar

Answer (score 0):

> "Yet again, I am confused about how java load's it's files."

When loading an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource), you always want to load from the class path, *not* by `File`. `File` will look for resources in the file system, which may work on *your* file system, but once deployed on a jar, *will not* work on other systems, and most likely not even yours.

For URLs, what you need to know is where the different ways to obtain a URL will search from. When using a class loader (`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`)the search will begin from the root, so this path

```
"res/shader/some_shader.glsl"
```

will work. On the other hand, when just using `getClass().getResource()` *without* the class loader, the search will begin from the calling class and its package location. That's the the extra `/` to traverse back in the file structure.

```
"/res/shader/some_shader.glsl"
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have no idea what you're doing wrong, but I have no problems. You can see the code. I exported it to jar. It works both in Eclipse *and* in the jar

package stackoverflow;

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestImagWithEclipse {
    private static final String PATH = "/res/shader/stack_reverse.png";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = TestImagWithEclipse.class.getResource(PATH);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(icon), "It works", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When using the getClass.getResource() with the preceeding / , I even get a "not found" in Eclipse ...

Comment: @salbeira Run the examples from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22712062/2587435), using your own paths, and let me know what happens.

Comment: Using the 'Utility.class.getClassLoader().getResource(file)' with preceeding / I get the resource in eclipse, but not in the jar, if I use Utility.class.getResource(file) with the preceeding / I do not find the resource in eclipse. What I did already test was using no / in Utility.class.getClassLoader().getResource(file) , where it works within Eclipse but not the .jar , what I did not test was using no / in Utility.class.getResource(file) in and outside of Eclipse

Comment: @salbeira see my UPDATE. Not sure what you're doing wrong but I have no problems.

Comment: I would love to know that, too ... Though ... right now I use 3 different projects and the Utility class is in another project than the resources I try to load, but they all get packaged into the same .jar ...