# java netbeans getClass().getResource(filename) return null

Tags: java, netbeans, getresource

I have a picture resource in my netbeans project and the `getResource(...)` method returns `null`, for every combination. Can you see what I am doing wrong from this screenshot?

[image: Netbeans screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried `getResource("/javafxaddress/media/1414459175_Save.png");`. And please try to add the code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: The below link will help you to findout your issue.. would you mind trying this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Many thanks, Tom.  /javafxaddress/media/...png worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getClass()` returns `TreeTestController.class` (assuming the method is not called on a subclass), which is in the package `javafxaddress.view`. `getResource()` uses a path that is relative to the package of the class on which it is called, unless the path starts with `/`. So your code looks for the file in the package `javafxaddress.view.media`, and the file is in fact in the package `javafxaddress.media`.

So the path should be `/javafxaddress/media/1414459175_Save.png`.

Answer (score 0):

See if either of these work:

```
getResource("/media/1414459175_Save.png")
```

or

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("media/1414459175_Save.png")
```

(notice one with and one without a prefixed slash)