# "FXMLLoader.constructLoadException" when trying to run java fx application

Tags: java, xml, javafx

I already searched the deepest depths of the interweb but no answer will seem to be found -.-

The problem is in my javaFx programm i want to write. But i can't make it any further than adding the controller class. I followed nearly every tutorial a could find, but the issue still remains unknown to me.

This is the exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/U:/BankingSolutions/MediaCenterFX/bin/main/ressources/view/MainUI.fxml:12

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:976)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:738)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3120)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /java/controllers/MainUIController
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:925)
... 24 more
```

and this is the code. there are thre classes: The Main.class, my MainUI.fxml which i created using scenebuilder 2 and my MainUIController.class which should obviously work as the mainuis controller

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/main/ressources/view/MainUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); 
    }
}

_______________________________________________

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="/java/controllers/MainUIController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane01" layoutX="657.0" layoutY="304.0" prefHeight="336.0" prefWidth="403.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <bottom>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="bp_bottom" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </bottom>
         <left>
            <GridPane fx:id="bp_left_grid" prefHeight="680.0" prefWidth="238.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="btn_search" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Suche" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                     <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </GridPane.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="btn_series" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Serien" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="btn_download" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Download" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="btn_movies" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Filme" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="btn_exit" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Beenden" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="btn_settings" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Optionen" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="btn_dashboard" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="Dashboard" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>

               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </left>
         <top>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="bp_top" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="headlabel" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="737.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1920.0" text="Dashboard" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="48.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </top>
         <center>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="bp_center" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
         <right>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="bp_right" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </right>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>

______________________________________________

package main.java.controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class MainUIController{

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;

    @FXML // fx:id="btn_search"
    private Button btn_search; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btn_movies"
    private Button btn_movies; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btn_exit"
    private Button btn_exit; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btn_series"
    private Button btn_series; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="bp_right"
    private AnchorPane bp_right; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="bp_bottom"
    private AnchorPane bp_bottom; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="borderPane01"
    private BorderPane borderPane01; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="headlabel"
    private Label headlabel; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="bp_left_grid"
    private GridPane bp_left_grid; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="bp_top"
    private AnchorPane bp_top; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="root"
    private AnchorPane root; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btn_download"
    private Button btn_download; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btn_dashboard
    private Button btn_dashboard; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="bp_center"
    private AnchorPane bp_center; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="btn_settings"
    private Button btn_settings; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    void initialize() {
        assert root         != null : "fx:id=\"root\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert borderPane01 != null : "fx:id=\"borderPane01\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert bp_top       != null : "fx:id=\"bp_top\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert headlabel    != null : "fx:id=\"headlabel\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert bp_left_grid != null : "fx:id=\"bp_left_grid\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert bp_center    != null : "fx:id=\"bp_center\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert bp_right     != null : "fx:id=\"bp_right\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert bp_bottom    != null : "fx:id=\"bp_bottom\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert btn_search   != null : "fx:id=\"btn_search\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert btn_series   != null : "fx:id=\"btn_series\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert btn_movies   != null : "fx:id=\"btn_movies\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert btn_download != null : "fx:id=\"btn_download\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert btn_settings != null : "fx:id=\"btn_settings\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert btn_dashboard!= null : "fx:id=\"dashboard\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";
        assert btn_exit     != null : "fx:id=\"btn_exit\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainUI.fxml'.";

        btn_search.setOnAction(value -> {
            System.out.println("Search pressed"); //TODO
        });
        btn_series.setOnAction(value ->{
            System.out.println("series pressed");
        });
        btn_movies.setOnAction(value ->{
            System.out.println("movies pressed");
        });
        btn_download.setOnAction(value ->{
            System.out.println("download pressed");
        });
        btn_settings.setOnAction(value ->{
            System.out.println("settings pressed");
        });
        btn_dashboard.setOnAction(value ->{
            System.out.println("dashboard pressed");
        });
        btn_exit.setOnAction(value ->{
            System.out.println("exit pressed");
        });


    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here is my package structure:

```
src
|-application
    |here is my main application
|-main
    |-java
        |-controllers
            |here are my controllers
        |-dao
        |-service
    |-ressources
        |-css
        |-images
        |-view
           |here are the fxml files
```

Comment: Considering `main/resources` is just the path to your classpath, have you tried replacing `getClass().getResource("/main/ressources/view/MainUI.fxml")` with `getClass().getResource("/view/MainUI.fxml")`?

Comment: Can you add the code for the fxml as well. I am of the opinion that you have incorrect for the controller in your fmxl as well.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess the package of the `MainUIController` is wrong. `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /java/controllers/MainUIController` says the class is in package `java.controllers` but the class itself defines the package as: `package main.java.controllers;`

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yeah i already tried that :/

Comment: @Malaka I edited my post and added my package structure to it. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change the project structure. The resources should not be resided in the sources itself. So my suggestion is the following project structure:

```
src
|-main
    |-java <-- This should be your 'sources root'
        |-application <-- The application itself is within the new sources root
        |-controllers
            |here are my controllers
        |-dao
        |-service
    |-resources <-- all resources (css files, images, fxml files) should be with a subfolder of the resources. This folder should be marked as 'resources root'
        |-css
        |-images
        |-view
            |here are the fxml files
```

This structure can be set up in any IDE. How you can set it up depends on the IDE itself. Normally you can simply right-click the folder in the overview and mark is as sources/resources root. The exact names for 'source root' and 'resources root' depend on the IDE.

The `Main` is now in the package `application` and the `MainUIController` is in the package `controllers`.

In the FXML-File you should specify:

```
fx:controller="controllers.MainUIController"
```

Loading the FXML-File should work with:

```
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/MainUI.fxml"));
```

---

As a reference for the following explanation, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception):
The `ClassLoader` always starts at the root of your resources. If you only use `getClass`, the path to the resource is a relative path. After dealing with it several times, I for myself have decided to always use absolute paths and therefore use the `getClassLoader`.
As explained in the link above, please note that

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/MainUI.fxml");
```

could be replaced by

```
getClass().getResource("view/MainUI.fxml");
```

I think that I somewhere read, that it is better to directly use the `InputStream` if available, as dealing with URLs within JAR-Files can be tricky sometimes (but I currently can't find a reference to support that). So as an alternative to the `getResource(..)`, you could use:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("view/MainUI.fxml");
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Had it like that except for the application folder to be inside the java folder. The textbox must have messed around with my spacings

Comment: You can generate a layout as MalaKa suggests by using a [JavaFX Maven archetype](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-basic-archetype) (though it may confuse you more than help if you have no familiarity with Maven).

Comment: Mhmm.. the getClassLoader() - appears to be unknown.. do i miss any imports here or something?

Comment: @PooBucket Yes, I'm sorry. Please see the updated line, that should work.

Comment: Thank you, i rearranged the package structure, by placing the application folder within the java package and overworked the used paths and now it runs great! Thank you for awesome support!

Comment: Thank you, also works for me. But even though my problem is solved, i am still curious about what the difference between FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(... and FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(... is o.O

Comment: You're welcome. I've also added some more explanation.

Comment: A lot of your explanation seems incorrect to me. `getClass().getResource()` and `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` do the exact same thing: see [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-): `getClass().getResource()` delegates to the call on the class loader. The difference between `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` and `FXMLLoader.load(InputStream)` is that the first is a `static` method while the second is an instance method (so your code `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...))` won't even compile).

Comment: @James_D Thank you, you are absolutely right about the `FXMLLoader`. I've also changed the line and the explanation of `getClass()` vs `getClass().getClassLoader()` for clearification.

Comment: As one more note on the `FXMLLoader`, if you use the `load(InputStream)` method you will lose any location-based information: i.e. [Location Resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution) will not work in your FXML. If you have an FXML resource (file, etc) then you should use a URL-based load; imo you should only use the InputStream load in the rare case you are generating a stream "on the fly" (i.e. there is no resource). I prefer `FXMLLoader l = new FXMLLoader(URL); Parent root = l.load();`

Answer (score 3):

The `fx:controller` attribute is expecting the fully qualified classname of the controller class. I.e. assuming you have

```
package main.java.controllers ;

public class MainUIController { ... }
```

you should have

```
fx:controller="main.java.controllers.MainUIController"
```

Comment: I already tried that out, but thank you. :/ but it doesn't semm to change anything

Comment: If you read the stack trace, it is clear that the `fx:controller` is the problem. I updated the answer slightly after reading your comments above.

Comment: whoa sorry dude, i tried your answer again and improved it with Malakas suggestion of package architecture and now it works just fine!! Awesome :)