# relative path doesn't work when executing jar

Tags: java, io

i am developping an application where i have to specify the path of a file called dao.properties it works just fine but when i execute the jar using the cmd : java -jar StockManagement.jar i get the error that the file is not found (it works fine in netbeans)
the class and the file are in the same folder.
i've tried a lot of relative paths and nothing works so this is my last hope
here is the code and the hierarchy:

[image: Hierarchy]

[image: Code]

thank y in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7098501/1352766 This should provide some information to you about your problem.

Comment: Could you also post the snippet of code you are using to attempt to load your file?

Comment: Can i do it in comments ?

Comment: It would be better to edit your answer and add the code snippets. That way anyone coming later doesn't have to search through comments to find all the information.

Comment: I saw you accepted an answer, did you figure out your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the way you're using ClassLoader is it looking for a file path relative to where it is being called.

From the picture, it seems that you're using ClassLoader from the DAOFactory class, is that right? You're declaring the path to your file to be

```
stock/DAO/dao.properties
```

If you're calling it from DAOFactory, Java looks for the file in

```
<where DAOFactory is>/stock/DAO/dao.properties
```

If DAOFactory and dao.properties reside in the same file I think your file path should just be

```
dao.properties
```

So it looks in the same folder that DAOFactory is in.

EDIT: Use DAOFactory class to read in properties file.

Using something like the following code snippet, call this function from the DAOFactory class using just the main method to try to see if you can read the properties file without anything else. Change any classes or names you need to to work on your local machine.

```
public static String getProperty(String property) {
  String value = "";

  try (InputStream is = DAOFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("dao.properties")) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    prop.load(is);
    value = prop.getProperty(property);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return value;
}
```

Comment: Hi morgan thanks for your answer
they are in the same folder and i've tried this before posting here, it didn't workd

Comment: At some point I saw you were using the Thread to attempt to read in your properties file. What if you use the DAOFactory class instead of a thread? Look at edited answer above?

Comment: This is what i did Morgan, i used the DAOFactory instead of the thread 
as Fillippo suggedted 
your comment also helped a lot i understood some things that was ambiguous for me Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, if you found my or Filipoo's answer you can upvote and/or accept our answer to show your appreciation.

Comment: i've done it i received that  it will take time to appear publicly because i am new here

Comment: Okay, just letting you know. When I was new to SO I didn't know about accepting answers or upvoting till about my fourth question.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is in your code base you should use the classLoader to load it.

Comment: Thank you Filippo for your answer
This is exactly what i am Doing

Comment: This generally works for me this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path_relative)

Comment: this is what i do i am new here i can't add the image in this comment i will add it in the post

Comment: You are using the context class loader of the current thread and not the classloader of the class. What you are doing is correct but the relative path to pass may change

Comment: you are right, i've got you, but how to adapt the relative path

Comment: i can"t use your suggestion because my methode is static :/

Comment: If you have jdk source code attached to your IDE you can debug and see what is the absolute path it's trying to access to build the URL of you resource and adapt your relative path consequently