# Spring mvc + maven: cannot access images

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm using a standard maven archetype of webapp, so I put my images folder under src/main/resources directory and in the war package it goes under WEB-INF/classes/ directory.

My project tree is in the following image [image]

So the images dir is in the classpath and i load it via getResource

```
final String path ="/resources/images/disegno.svg";
URL imagePath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
```

but i get

```
Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when declaring `path`
Also in .jsp, I try to access the image in this way:

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/WEB-INF/classes/images/disegno.svg"/>
```

but no image is displayed, even if it links to

```
http://localhost:8080/svgTest/WEB-INF/classes/images/disegno.svg
```

I cannot understand how maven works in this situation, and cannot find a complete guide, because everywhere all looks so easy, so I don't know which error i'm doing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making 3 mistakes.

First: `ClassLoader.getResource()` expects a path that does NOT start with a `/`.

Second: what is under `src/main/resources` in the source project goes at the root of the classpath. There is no `resources` package, as your screenshot of WEB-INF/classes shows. So your path should be

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/disegno.svg")
```

Third: by design, everything undex WEB-INF is not accessible from the browser. Everything out of WEB-INF is. So if you want the browser to be able to download your image, it should be in the `src/main/webapp` folder, not in `src/main/resources`. Of cource, once it's there, you won't be able to load it with the ClassLoader anymore, since it won't be in the classpath anymore. If you need to load it in addition to make it directly available to the browser, then use `ServletContext.getResource()`.