# this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath() is NPE possible here?

Tags: java, classloader, absolute-path, file-location

I got code review comment that below line could return `NPE`

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()
```

As I'm refering self class, is any chance I can get `NPE`?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098501/1665592) which says if I load external file then there is `NPE` possibility, am I right ?

Comment: getResource("") -> not sure, but I guess this could.

Comment: can you please answer it why? and how can I overcome it? would be very beneficial for me.

Comment: Yes. Read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)). http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: you could add a simple null-check

Comment: The term "resource (name)" is subject to a class loader's implementation. Under the default system class loader and `URLClassLoader`, `getResource("")` will actually return `null` when the loader's search path is either unspecified or does not include any directory entries. Some other loader could prefer to unconditionally return `null` or attach special semantics to the empty resource name or whatever.

Comment: Can someone help me to load current class path if my expression evaluates into `NPE`

Comment: Your best chances are with `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, or, if applicable (JDK < 9), `((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).getURLs()`. But there's never 100% guarantee that it won't return `null` in the general case, because it ultimately depends on what/how launches the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code to avoid `NPE`

```
Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString()
```

Yes, from comment this JavaDoc is much helpful.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

```
getResource
public URL getResource(String name)
Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way that is independent of the location of the code.
The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource.

This method will first search the parent class loader for the resource; if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will invoke findResource(String) to find the resource.

Parameters:
name - The resource name
Returns:
A URL object for reading the resource, or null if the resource could not be found or the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource.
Since:
1.1
```