# Location is required when execute JAR builded with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, nullpointerexception

I habe a big problem with my JAR File. I work with IntelliJ and hav following Filestructure of my project...

[Filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4NCt.png)

and got this error when I want to start the compiled JAR File:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qm2C.png)

The thing is, wehn I start the program in IntelliJ it works fine...
The following code I use to get the resource out of the folder:

```
URL loginScreen = getClass().getResource("/fxml/loginScreen.fxml");
        AnchorPane login = FXMLLoader.load(loginScreen);
```

even that doesn't work:

```
URL loginScreen = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("loginScreen.fxml");
        AnchorPane login = FXMLLoader.load(loginScreen);
```

When I want to test the Path and do

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/fxml/loginScreen.fxml")); 
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/loginScreen.fxml"));
```

I get the full path. Now i compile it to JAR and I get 'null'.

After a lot of google search and testing any of this links doesn't work:

[JavaFX "Location is required." even though it is in the same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package)

[this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("...") and NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception?noredirect=1&lq=1)

.

What I doing wrong? Sorry for my language ;)

Comment: Open JAR file and check if fxml file is really inside.

Comment: Yeah their inside: [http://prntscr.com/jt3c3a]

Comment: I can only suggest to try it with `"./fxml/loginScreen.fxml"` or `"../fxml/loginScreen.fxml"`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work...

Comment: Well can't really help you, I tried reproducing your problem but I couldn't do it, for me using `"/fxml/example.fxml"` worked fine, I don't really know much about Intellij's jar building as I use maven for such tasks but there might be some configuration.