# Maven JavaFX Project Unable to Find FXML FIle Using GetResource?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have a standard (Non JavaFX) Maven Java Project in Netbeans. The first thing it is supposed to do is load a .fxml file, but I can't seem to find it using `getClass().getResource()`.

This is unusual, because this project is imported from a standard Java project, which runs just fine without error.

Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Main_PanelController controller = new Main_PanelController(this);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main_Panel.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    URL url = getClass().getResource("Main_Panel.fxml");
    System.out.println("URL: " + url);
    System.exit(0);
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(new FileInputStream(Paths.get("Pictures", "SBU Emblem.png").toFile())));
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    stage.setTitle("Simple Knisley Citation Tool α 0.5");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
```

The URL always comes back as `null`.

& The File Hierarchy:

[image: Hierarchy]

I have the `System.out.println` as a test method to see if the URL object comes back as null or not. According to everything I've read about `getClass().getResource()` it should get any object in the same package as the calling class, which `Main_Panel.fxml` is.

Here is the Jar file structure from the `target` folder after `Clean & Build` has run using the command `jar tf Simple-Knisley-0.5-Alpha-jackofall.jar`

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/protonmail/
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/CitationDiskManager.class
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/Main_PanelController.class
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/CitationGenerator$GeneratorType.class
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/CitationGenerator.class
com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/Main.class
.netbeans_automatic_build
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.protonmail.sarahszabo.simpleknisley/
META-INF/maven/com.protonmail.sarahszabo.simpleknisley/Simple-Knisley/
META-INF/maven/com.protonmail.sarahszabo.simpleknisley/Simple-Knisley/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.protonmail.sarahszabo.simpleknisley/Simple-Knisley/pom.properties
```

I'm using Java 8_171 on Netbeans 8.2 on Kubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Comment: Have a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception , in my opinion this has to do about Maven, if so I am not familiar with but you may try to use a full path like : `getClass().getResource("/com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/Main_Panel.fxml")`

Comment: There are a lot of people in the post in my previous commend who tweak the maven build path configuration system or the setting in general to fix the problem. So read some of their answers if my previous suggestion isn't working.

Comment: I not see FXML file in this jar. Une resource folder for fxml files.

Comment: Have you tried adding a "/" in front of your resource (`getClass().getResource("/Main_Panel.fxml");`)? That is a trap I always fall for when using that method.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the kind of project, but some project types require you to put the resources in a seperate "resource tree", i.e. there may be a seperate "Other sources" item in your project you need to move the fxmls to (and reproduce the correct package structure).

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Yep tried that, no luck. I saw that solution from my research on `getResource()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues going on here.

1. Maven expects (by default) resources to be in the `src/main/resources` directory.  It will only copy java files from `src/main/java` by default.  So move your `fxml` file to `src/main/resources/com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/Main_Panel.fxml`
2. `getClass().getResource()` expects you to give the full path to the resource that you want to load.  So in your case: `getClass().getResource("/com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/Main_Panel.fxml")`

Using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` allows you to specify the location of the resource you want to load as a relative path to the class you are calling it in:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Main_Panel.fxml")
```

Comment: Now when you say `/src/main` what packages should I create in Netbeans? Should I make the package `src/main/resources/com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/Main_Panel.fxml` or is the `src` essentially the same as the Source Code folder?

Comment: Yes, the full path you have above is what you should create. You might be better creating it on the command line rather than netbeans, incase it makes some assumptions you're not expecting.

Comment: I Made the `src/main/resources/com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core/` folder and swiched the `getResources ` call to `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Main_Panel.fxml")` as well as specifying the full path, but this appeared to be ineffective.

Comment: I also didn't see the `/src` folder or any of its children in the `jar tf` structure after building it again.

Comment: Did you move the fxml file to the new folder?

Comment: Yes, I moved it to `src/main/resources/com/protonmail/sarahszabo/simpleknisley/core`.

Comment: What do you see when you run `find src/main -type f` from the root directory of your project?