# Cannot read resource from jar

Tags: java

I have the following prefix:

```
String prefix = TemplatesReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("templates/").getPath();
```

and have method

```
public byte[] read(String pathToTemplate) {
   return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(prefix + pathToTemplate));
}
```

in intellij idea works correctly, but when starting jar an error occurs:

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/templates/request-orders/unmarked/RequestOrderUnmarked.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("...") and NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception)

Comment: @alain.janinm this is not helped

Comment: Are you using any plugin or script for packaging. In this case you should share more info for helping you.

Comment: <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: Your mistake was calling `getPath()`.  That *does not* return a valid file name, it merely returns the path portion of a URL.  A resource inside a .jar is just part of a .jar file, not a separate file.  You cannot use Path and Files to read it.  You can, however, use `getResourceAsStream` to read it.

Comment: Could you decompress the jar and verify if your template exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not assume that a resource is a file.  When the resource is inside a .jar file, it is a part of that .jar file;  it is no longer a separate file at all.

You cannot use Files or Paths to read the resource.

You cannot use the getPath() method of URL.  It *does not* return a file name.  It only returns the path portion of the URL (that is, everything between the URL’s scheme/authority and its query portion), which is not a file path at all.

Instead, read the resource using [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

```
private static final String RESOURCE_PREFIX = "/templates/";

public byte[] read(String pathToTemplate)
throws IOException {
    try (InputStream stream = TemplatesReader.class.getResource(
        RESOURCE_PREFIX + pathToTemplate)) {

        return stream.readAllBytes();
    }
}
```